# Can Visual Studio Code be prevented from indenting a level deeper after opening braces?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I enter "foo ()\n\t{\n"

```
foo ()
    {
        <- cursor is now here
```

I'd like it to be at the same level of indent as the line above (4 spaces in this example), not pushed in a level (8 spaces in this example). So:

```
foo ()
    {
    <- cursor here and all will be well in the world
```

I've tried completely turning off all the indent/tab settings I can find.  I'm even prepared to hack around with an extension so a pointer to any in-depth documentation around type/tab commands would also be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Well, erm, there is an Editor Setting in Preferences, where you can adjust the tabs "editor.tabSize": 4, but I don't there is any level scaling, but I've also discovered a little "hack". If you make double slashes after

```
{//
```

and hit return it looks like this:

```
{//
Hello_world!! 
}
```

Kind of silly, I guess.